# Filter nodes by a boolean value

Tags: json, jmeter, extract, jsonpath

I have to filter JSON by IsNew parameter (true or false)
Part of the JSON is below:

```
{
"data": [
  {
    "type": "users",
    "attributes": {
      "first-name": "student21",
      "last-name": "student21",
      "username": "student21",
      "role": "student",
      "IsNew": true
    },
    "relationships": {
      "groups": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "groups",
            "id": "123f"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "users",
    "attributes": {
      "first-name": "student23",
      "last-name": "student23",
      "email": "",
      "avatar-url": null,
      "username": "student23",
      "role": "student",
      "IsNew": false
    },
    "relationships": {
      "groups": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "groups",
            "id": "456"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ]
```

}

I've tried the following expressions:

$..data..[?(@.IsNew == true)].username,

$..data..[?(@.IsNew == 'true')].username,

$..data..[?(@.IsNew == "true")].username

All those expressions don't return any result.

I need to extract usernames for students with "IsNew" == true and "IsNew" == false separetely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To extract usernames for students with "IsNew" == true, use a JSON Extractor with following settings:

   - JSON Path Expression :`$.data..attributes[?(@.IsNew =~ /.*true/i)].username`
   - Match No. `-1` [to get all the matches for multiple students]

[image]

2. To extract usernames for students with "IsNew" == false, use a JSON Extractor with following settings:

   - JSON Path Expression :`$.data..attributes[?(@.IsNew =~ /.*false/i)].username`
   - Match No. `-1` [to get all the matches for multiple students]

[image]

3. Use following variables to process further:

   - ${FalseStudent_matchNr} or ${FalseStudent} if you have used Match No other than -1 in JSON Extractor
   - ${TrueStudent_matchNr} or ${TrueStudent} if you have used Match No other than -1 in JSON Extractor

[image]

Comment: are there any ways to check the expression in some Online Evaluator?

Comment: You can check using JMeter as well, 
 use Dummy Sampler and add the JSON to Response Data Section.
 Run the test.
 In View Result Tree, use the JSON Path Tester [from top left drop down] and test the expression.